# If you delete a character, does its designs stay?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In New Leaf, your character can make designs and display them on the ground to create "pathways". If a character puts down pathways and then you delete that character, will pathways still be there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My educated guess is no, they will not stay. According to [this forum thread](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/50570/t1882681-problem-with-making-path/) if you overwrite a design everything that uses that design will be changed to the new design. I would imagine deleting a character would have the same effect of overwriting those designs with 'nothing'.

After testing it I can confirm that any designs placed by the deleted character are removed.

This is still true even if another character has the same design in the same slot. I had the temporary character place a design that both characters happen to have and it still got deleted.

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: Just did. They get removed.

Answer (score -1):

No, unless you have them up in desplay or a different person has it/th it will never stay